# SignalR on hosting - virtualdirectory/signalr/hubs shows Error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, http-status-code-404, web-hosting

I have a SinglaR app (empty web application without any global.asax and RouteConfig) which works well.

*http://localhost:62673/signalr/hubs* shows 'ASP.NET SignalR JavaScript Library v2.2.0' javascript and it is working (I use Winforms client, not the javascript one).

But when I deploy it to the webhosting (virtual directory), on the address *http://myhosting.xxx/virtualdirectory/signalr/hubs* I get error 404 instead.

I have this in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

What else am I missing?

Thanx

Comment: Ok, I found it after a whole day. The directive _<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>_ in web.config is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it after a whole day. This directive in web.config is needed:

```
<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true"/>
```